# Secure directory File Upload with Carrierwave failing (production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I followed [this guide](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-To%3A-Secure-Upload) learning how to do file uploads to a secure directory on my server, rather than public (default). When I try to go to the show to view the links, I get:

```
undefined method `redocument' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0xa2ae338>
near: <%= link_to File.basename(f.redocument.url), "/uploads/#{f.id}/#{File.basename(f.redocument.url)}" %>
```

It is having trouble rendering the link. Am I missing something here? Am I not supposed to copy this code line by line? They don't specify whether or not I should be replacing 'redocument', but my model name is Entry, and the string the file's link is stored is mv_link. Anyone have any idea what the fix is?

Update: Hopefully in the right direction

I changed all the cases of 'f.redocument' to '@entry.mv_link'. Now on the show page, the link is there. However when I click it and try to download, the path specified by the controller is broken. This is what the controller was

```
def download
  path = "/#{redocument.redocument}"
  send_file path, :x_sendfile=>true
end
```

What should I change this path to?

Comment: Is this in a form, and f is the form object? If so, try `f.object.redocument.url`

Comment: Actually this is in the view... the same as what was done in the last line of the guide.

Comment: The error indicates it's in a form and that f is the form-builder object. Are you positive you're not in a form? What is the `f` variable?

Comment: I'm not sure... it is just given in the Carrierwave github code... I actually changed a few things based on the idea you gave me, so everywhere it says f.redocument.url, i changed it to  @entry.mv_link.url. Seems more correct, and the page actually shows up with the link, what do you know. However, when I click the link, and try to download it, the path is broken. I will edit my post with some info, one sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, going on a limb here... But I think you have something like this setup:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  mounts_uploader :mv_link, YourUploaderClass
end
```

In your controller, you need to find the Entry and then get the path form the mv_link

```
def download
  @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  send_file @entry.mv_link.path, disposition: 'attachment', x_sendfile: true
end
```

Comment: Well done my friend. What does disposition: 'attachment' do? I didn't add that, but it still works anyway. Also mines formatted :x_sendfile => true. Thanks this is the solution I was looking for.